# Need help getting authentication to work in all apps in a Django project

Tags: python, django

I'm starting up on Django, and am just a novice when it comes to server-side code.  All of my web coding experience is in the front-end and is limited to CSS, HTML, and basic javascript. But I thought it was time to take it up a notch and learn more about the back-end of things and decided to start here.  I went through Django's starting application guide successfully.  I'm not attempting to add an extension in and "soup up" the app.

I installed allauth for registration/user management.  I was able to set it up and successfully register, log-in, log-out with the default templates.

However when I load up the polls application which is within the same project, it doesn't seem to work...

Code in index.html (found under templates/polls/)under polls application that doesn't work.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <b>ALL GOOD</b>
{% else %}
    <b>Go sign-in first.</b>
{% endif %}
```

Code in sign-up.html (found under templates/account/) under accounts that does work.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    Good work
{% else %}
    Fail
{% endif %}
```

Am I missing an import statement somewhere?  Why does it work in one template folder but not the other?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What error message do you get? Are you using generic views to render the poll's index page?

Answer (score 1):

try `request.user.is_authenticated`instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `RequestContext(request)` and you have `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` the `user` variable will be accessible on your template.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth

I think that made more sense in my head.

`RequestContext` is from `from django.template import RequestContext` and when you

```
render_to_response("mytemplate.html",
    RequestContext(request, {"other_variable": other_value, "more": True}))
```

**or**

```
template.render(RequestContext(request, {"other_variable": other_value, "more": True}))
```

Simply put: you get access to a bunch of variables without specifying them.

---

**Edit :-**

I just found you could use `from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template` instead of `render_to_response`

```
direct_to_template(request, "mytemplate.html", {"other_variable": other_value, "more": True})
```

It does the same as the `render_to_response` line I gave above.

Answer (score 0):

Without more info it's hard to say, but my initial reaction is that you may not be passing the user variable to the template context in your view function.

i.e.:

```
def view(request):
    t = loader.get_template('index.html')
    c = Context({"user": request.user})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```